# Nvidia GeForce GTX on Notebooks is not the same, why don't they say so?

Tags: nvidia

I have:
GeForce GTX Mobile / Max-Q on my Lenovo Ideapad 3 Gaming but it was advertised as having a 1650.  Upon checking online this one is 10 to 15% slower.

I tried to return it but was told, "This is just the way it is for notebooks, you don't get the 1650 normal version which is for desktops".

Why don't notebook manufacturers put the "Mobile / Max-Q" part in their ads?

This is disappointing as I tried using Numba Python Cuda and the speedup is not very good.

Also, is this normal?  I bought this in Japan and that is what the Japanese retailer is telling me, refusing to accept a return.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your GPU is probably a real GTX 1650 and was not falsly advertised. The seller was right telling you that this is normal too since the laptop variants of GPU's generally don't get the same amount of cooling as the similarly named desktop GPU's, so they (nVidia/AMD, not Lenovo or the seller) have to tune the chip so that it uses less power, so it makes less heat. The only bad side effect of this is it performs a little less.

Also about that numba python cuda stuff, it probably uses more RAM than your GPU has availible (your GPU only has 4GB, just like all GTX 1650) which probably means it tries to cache to system RAM, which slows the GPU down.